# How can I import variables from terminal to shell?

Tags: python, terminal, command, prompt

Amateur question here, I now know how to use the ARGV command in terminal but id like to do the opposite, I'm not sure how to call it tho.

ex(in idle)

```
from sys import argv
script, one, two, three, four=argv
print("the script is called:", script)
print("the first variable is called:", one)
print("the second variable is called:", two)
print("the third variable is called:", three)
print("the fourth variable is called:", four)
```

in terminal

```
documents/user python 3.py do this backwards lol
```

I get(in terminal)

```
('the script is called:', '3.py')
('the first variable is called:', 'do')
('the second variable is called:', 'this')
('the third variable is called:', 'backwards')
('the fourth variable is called:', 'lol')
```

it works but I want the final output to be in shell instead and not in terminal, any help is appreciated

Comment: What is "shell" for you? Which is the difference from "terminal"?

Comment: You cannot do that, and you do not want to do that, either. First things first, you confuse the IDE (idle) and the python shell. The shell is the same in the IDE and in the terminal. The IDE is simply a convenient tool to develop your program ("D" stands for "development"). Once the program is developed, it is run from the terminal.

Comment: you mean standard input `sys.stdin`?